# Node.Js Req.Body Empty after Post

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Im using ExpressJS and AngularJS in my app. And when i try to make a post, req.body is empty.

Express

```
  var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  routes = require('./server/routes/routes'),

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); 

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

routes(app, passport);

app.listen(port);
```

Post

```
 app.post('/api/employee', function(req, res) {

    var employee = req.body;
    console.log(employee);

    // Create employee
    Employee.addEmployee(employee, function(err, employee) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);
      res.json(employee);
    });
  });
```

Index.html

```
    <form class="form-signin">
      <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Novo serviço</h2>

      <label for="inputPhone">Telefone:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="employee.phone" name="phone" placeholder="" required>

      <label for="inputCpf">CPF</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="employee.cpf" name="cpf" placeholder="" required>

      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="createEmployee()" type="submit">Confirmar Serviço</button>
    </form>
```

AngularJS

```
    .factory('employeeProxy', ['$resource',
        function($resource) {
          return $resource('/api/employee/:id', {}, {
            save: {
              method: 'POST',
              isArray: false
            },
            update: {
              method: 'PUT',
              isArray: true
            },
            delete: {
              method: 'DELETE',
              params: {
                id: '@id'
              },
              isArray: true
            },
            query: {
              method: 'GET',
              params: {
                id: '@id'
              },
              isArray: false
            }
          })
        }
      ])
```

AngularJs Controller Function

```
$scope.createEmployee = function() {
  employeeService.createEmployee($scope.employee, function(data) {
    $scope.callbackMessage = data.message;
  }, function(err) {
    $scope.callbackMessage = err.data.message;
  });
};
```

AngularJS Service

```
self.createEmployee = function(employee, successCallback, error) {
  employeeProxy.save(employee, successCallback, error);
}
```

Am I missing something? I am going crazy already. I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Where is the code of your POST method (on the server)? It could maybe help.

Comment: Just added. Thanks for reminding me

Comment: Do you get an empty object? I mean, does `console.log(employee)` literally print `{}`?

Comment: Actually, it prints [ ]

Comment: Could you add your Controller function `createEmployee()` you call **on-click** as well, please? :-)

Comment: Mmmh... and  the `createEmployee()` method of your `employeeService`? Backend looks OK so far, I think what's wrong is on the frontend.

Comment: I'm not familiar with $resource but how does the object gets pass. You have {} after the url. Maybe is that. ($resource('/api/employee/:id', {} ....)